# DataGridView & 'System.NullReferenceException' error

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to load my textboxes with my DataGridView values as follow but I am getting a 
" A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"
error, the program is still workable though despite this. Anyone knows what's wrong?

Many Thanks.

Code:

```
For iloop = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count
        For Each cCtrl As Control In Panel2.Controls
            If TypeOf cCtrl Is TextBox Then
                Dim txtBox As TextBox
                txtBox = cCtrl
                If (txtBox.Name.Substring(9, 6)) = ((DataGridView2.Rows.Item(iloop).Cells(0).Value).substring(0, 6)) Then
                    txtBox.Text = DataGridView2.Rows.Item(iloop).Cells(3).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: what line does it hit the error?

Comment: Hi, this line is: "If (txtBox.Name.Substring(9, 6)) = ((DataGridView2.Rows.Item(iloop).Cells(0).Value).substring(0, 6)) Then" ((DataGridView2.Rows.Item(iloop).Cells(0).Value).substring(0, 6)) is actually the one that is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an if condition for  `If DataGridView2.Rows.Item(iloop).Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing Then` before you take the substring of the value.

Comment: Thanks but checking for null didn't help, I just discovered that if I were to assign '((DataGridView2.Rows.Item(iloop).Cells(0).Value).substring(0, 6))' to a String variable, I will get that exception error.